# ISR(TIMERn_OVF_vect) interrupt not work Atmega 2560

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, atmega, atmelstudio

i have a problem whith ISR() - this function is not work. I use Atmel Studio 7, USBASP programmer, AVRDude_Prog 3.3 and RobotDyn board with Atmega 2560(Robotdyn Mega +WiFi R3 ATmega2560+ESP8266).

I want read signal from HC-SR04 sensor for mesurment distance. I read datasheet about Atmega 2560 and settings of my timers counters: start from 0 counter up to 4th counter.I tried set up each one setting of interrupts and it's not help me(

I use LEDs on PORTA for find problem with counters, interrupts and settings. But now i don't have any result.

And this simple code for enable LED, when ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) launch not work too, but i copy this from youtube video for test(https://youtu.be/vl5H_Q1slYY?t=1531).

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define LED1 0
#define LED2 1


int main(void)
{
    TCCR0B = (1<<CS00) | (1 << CS02); //8Mhz/1024/255
    TIMSK0 = (1<<TOIE0);

    DDRA = 0xff;
    PORTA = 0b00000100;

    sei();

    while(1)
    {

    }

}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    PORTA ^= (1<<LED1);
}
```

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SREG _SFR_IO8(0x3f) 

unsigned char OVF_counter, zamer_1, zamer_T, zamer_t, duty;
unsigned long t, T, T1, f, num;
unsigned int rising_1, rising_2, falling;

ISR(TIMER4_OVF_vect)
{
    PORTA = 0b00001111;
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    PORTA = 0b00000011;
}

ISR(TIMER4_CAPT_vect)
{

}

void init_timer (void)
{   

    TIMSK4 |= (1 << ICIE4)|(1 << TOIE4);    

    TCCR4B |= (1 << ICNC4)|(1 << CS42);  

    TIFR4 |= (1 << TOV4);

    TCCR0B = (1 << CS01);

    TIFR0 |= (1 << TOV0);

    SREG  = 0b10000000; 

    SREG  = 0x80;

}

void capture (void)
{
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(10);
    PORTB = 0x00;

    rising_1 = ICR4; 
    T=TCNT4;
    TCCR4B &= ~(1 << ICES4); 

    falling = ICR4;
    T1=TCNT4;          
    TCCR4B |= (1 << ICES4);   
    t = falling - rising_1  ;
}

int main(void)
{
    SREG = 0x80;
    DDRL = 0x00;
    DDRB = 0xff;
    DDRA = 0xff; 
    init_timer(); 

    while (1) 
    {   
        capture();

        if(t >= 1000000)
        {
            PORTA = 0b00000000;
        }
        if(t >= 100000)
        {
            PORTA = 0b00000111;
        }
        else if(t >= 1)
        {
            PORTA = 0b00000011;
        }
        else if(t >= 0)
        {
            PORTA = 0b00000001;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTA = 0b00001111;
            num=0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In your second code I don't see you turning on interrupts `sei();`.  In your first code, maybe try turning on interrupts earlier.

Comment: In the second code i used SREG register and anable global interrupts by switch last bit "I" on this register. Interrupts not work in second code becouse timer/counter 0 and timer/counter 4 dont work together.

Comment: First code, could You tell something about clock of this MCU? I see F_CPU 16MHz and then in comment 8MHz, which value is real? Maybe the fuse bits are diffrent than you think they are.

Comment: I don't understand second code. I mean I don't know what you wanted to do here. Imho maintaining PORTA in that way (in while(1) and asynchronus ISRs) is bad practice. In addition, could You check that SREG asssigments are correct?